# Webpack errors after migrating to Next 13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, next.js

After upgrading Next to version 13 our application does not build it looks like webpack have problem with imports and exports and presumably typescript

```
../../libs/queries/src/lib/groq/searchFaq.ts
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:37)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> export const searchFaqQuery = (market: string, language: string, searchTerm: string) => {
|   const searchTermArray = searchTerm.split(' ').map((word) => word + '*');
|   const queryFilters = `market == '${market}' && language == '${language}' && _type == 'faq' && !(_id in path("drafts.**"))`;

Import trace for requested module:
../../libs/queries/src/lib/groq/searchFaq.ts
../../libs/queries/src/index.ts

../../libs/utils/src/lib/components/atoms/BulletListWrapper/BulletListWrapper.tsx
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (4:5)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| import * as Styled from './BulletListWrapper.style';
| 
> type TBulletListWrapper = {
|   children: React.ReactNode;
| };

Import trace for requested module:
../../libs/utils/src/lib/components/atoms/BulletListWrapper/BulletListWrapper.tsx
../../libs/utils/src/lib/components/atoms/index.ts
../../libs/utils/src/lib/components/index.ts
../../libs/utils/src/index.ts
```

The list of errors is longer but are very similiar to those above. My next.config.js looks this way:

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    NEXT_PUBLIC_TOKEN: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_TOKEN,
    NEXT_PUBLIC_PREVIEW_SECRET: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_PREVIEW_SECRET,
    NEXT_PUBLIC_PROJECT_ID: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_PROJECT_ID,
  },
  i18n: {
    defaultLocale: 'et',
    locales: ['et', 'ru'],
  },
  basePath: '/ee',
  reactStrictMode: true,
  images: {
    domains: ['cdn.images.io'],
    formats: ['image/webp'],
  },
  experimental: {
    forceSwcTransforms: true,
  },
  swcMinify: true,
  webpack(config) {
    config.resolve.fallback = { fs: false, path: false };
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/,
      issuer: {
        and: [/\.(js|ts)x?$/],
      },
      use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
    });

    return config;
  },
};
```

Would you please point me in the right direction? We have a monorepo with NX and I after upgrade everything works without a problem in development, but when it came to bulding the app there seems to be a problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like an issue with `nx` using deprecated nextjs internals. The root cause is described in https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/46374#issuecomment-1446065787 and was fixed in nx@15.8.7.